# worker class with timer ensure that method is only invoked once

Tags: c#

I am currently using this preliminary approach:

```
public class AskingForWorkClass
{
    private static Timer _timer;

    public void Start()
        {
            // catchup with outstanding work
            DoWork(this, null);

        _timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 }; // one second
        _timer.Elapsed += DoWork;
        _timer.Start();
        }

        private void DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

The intention is that when Start is invoked all outstanding work is done first. After that a timer is used to invoke DoWork, which checks for more work does it. Please note that I would like to prevent DoWork from being hit by the timer if it is still running from the last invocation by the timer. Is this possible? Basically, DoWork should only be run by one process at the time.

Comment: Stop the timer on DoWork and restart before exiting from it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just start / stop the timer in your `DoWork` method:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();

   // .. do stuff ...

    _timer.Start();
}
```

Note: depending on which `Timer` class you're using, you may not have `Start` and `Stop` and instead need to use the `Modify` method, but you get the idea.

**UPDATE**

So based on comments this is a solution which should prevent any incident of `DoWork` executing twice, regardless of the `Interval` property.

```
public class AskingForWorkClass
{
    private static Timer _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public void Start()
        {
            // catchup with outstanding work
            DoWork(this, null);

        _timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 }; // one second
        _timer.Elapsed += DoWork;
        _timer.Start();
        }

        private void DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _event.WaitOne();

            // ... do stuff here ... 

            _event.Set();
        }
}
```

What happens here is that that when `DoWork` is entered it will wait until the event has been set to the signaled state and block the current thread until that happens.  Note that the construction of the event `new AutoResetEvent(true)` creates the event in the signaled state so the first time `DoWork` is called it doesn't block forever.

Once the `WaitOne` call passes, the event automatically sets itself back to the unsignaled state meaning that future calls to the `DoWork` method will be blocked.  Then finally we call the `Set` method which puts the event back into the signaled state until the next `WaitOne` call.

Comment: This still has the possibly of executing twice if the timer interval is small enough.  Better to set AutoReset to false and then just call _timer.Start() after DoWork finishes.

Comment: @JesseWeigert Agreed, that's a good thing to note for the OP.  But based on his sample code I think this solution is fine and has the advantage of being a bit simpler.

Comment: I would prefer it to be as robust as possible (-:

Comment: Thanks. Will check out tomorrow.

Comment: Just to be clear, I may have overstated the "... regarless of the  `Interval` propery".  I can imagine some very edge cases where you could still make it run twice, but I think this is a pretty robust solution.